# Dropbox API check if file is updated

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I was searching on some method to check for when a file is updated on dropbox to advise the user. The best I found was a code snippet belonging to the Sync API which observes if there are any changes:

```
// First, create a file for you to change
DBPath *path = [[DBPath root] childPath:@"change-me.txt"];
self.file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:path error:nil];

// Next, register for changes on that file
[self.file addObserver:self block:^() {

// This block will be called every time your file changes

// if newerStatus is not nil, it means a newer version is available
DBFileStatus *newerStatus = file.newerStatus;
if (newerStatus) {

if (!newerStatus.cached) {
NSLog(@"newerStatus.cached == NO; this means the file downloading");
} else {

// Update to the newly available version and print it out
[file update:nil];
NSLog(@"The file is done downloading: %@", [file readString:nil]);
}
}
}];
```

Any ideas? I was actually thinking to add the Sync api just to use this feature, but I don't think that adding two dropbox SDK's is the correct solution.

Comment: i think there is no other easy way you can do it, without using Sync Api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the Sync API and we are working hard to make sure much of the functionality of the Core API makes it over to the Sync API. Otherwise you could use the [/delta endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#delta) of the REST API which actually powers the Sync API.